# Setting up https on a server with Phoenix/Elixir and nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, elixir, phoenix-framework

I know how to setup https for, say, clojure web app with nginx. How to do that for Phoenix?
In the `prod.exs` I have this:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "my_website.com", port: 443],
  http: [port: 4000],
#  https: [port: 443,
#          keyfile: System.get_env("SOME_APP_SSL_KEY_PATH"),
#          certfile: System.get_env("SOME_APP_SSL_CERT_PATH")],

  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json"
```

I have this:

```
ssl_certificate:  /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_app.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_app.com/privkey.pem;
```

I want to use nginx with Phoenix as well.

1) Should I remove "http: [port: 4000]," compeletely from "prod.exs"?

2) Should I instead uncomment "https: [port: 443,...." ? Or should I have them both? I don't want to website to be accessible at http or I'd let nginx take care of it by redirecting a user from http to https.

3) Or should I remove https and http and let nginx handle that?

4) How about the key "url" and its "port"?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Nginx to terminate the SSL part of the connection, then you leave the app server configured for HTTP and any port you like (4000 is fine as long as you configure Nginx to forward to it).  If your server is configured correctly, it will not answer HTTP port 4000 requests, thus the SSL cannot be bypassed.

The SSL configuration you are referring to at the app server level configures the app server to terminate the SSL connection (no Nginx necessary).  Phoenix apps are all "full featured" web servers thanks to [cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy).  Thus, they can handle the SSL termination as well as serving the application's dynamic and static assets.

The URL configuration is so your application knows its domain and can generate full urls as well as paths.

Comment: It is not theory, it is the exact instructions for what you need to do.  Let me see if I can make it more simple for you since you seem not to understand clear instructions.  Leave the `http: [port: 4000]` part in your configuration. Do not uncomment the `https: [port: 443,....` as Nginx will terminate the SSL connection for you. Configure your Nginx instance to forward requests to `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. Last, don't be so rude when someone is trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're set on using nginx in front of your Phoenix app then use nginx to terminate the ssl connection (your option 3).  You still need to configure http in Phoenix though since nginx will proxy to your app using http.  Therefore:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "my_website.com", port: 4000],
  http: [port: 4000]
```

Which assumes you will configure nginx to proxy to your app on port 4000.  You will also want to adjust the `host` config key to be the base url of your site since any URL's you generate will use this base name (as Jason mentioned).

Comment: so I don't need the key "https" in Phoenix config?

Comment: are you sure `url: [host: "my_website.com", port: 4000],` -- it's port 4000 and not 80? this says http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/serving-your-application-behind-a-proxy it should be 80

Comment: The port should be `80` as this is used to generate full paths in the routing.